# Change items style when moving elements in jquery-ui sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two columns, that are jquery-ui sortable. In the left column are choosen items, in the right are all not choosen. You can move items (`li` elements) between both. Each element can be either in the left one or in the right column. The first element in the left column (choosen) is not sortable and cant be moved (name ID). Elements in the left column have different style as elements in the right column, also in the left column each `li` element is on self line, but in the right column they are floated.

Here is an image of that:

[image]

Everything is working fine, but when user is moving element between columns, I need the element change its style (while is moving = left mouse button is down), when is over left or right column. By changing its style I mean, when f.e. I start to move element `Telefón` from left to right, when I will be over right column, this element should change its background color to gray and display not in the whole line, but only in its width and ad versa.

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/5wy04t7y/1/)

I cant figure out, how this can be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your sortable options:

```
over: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.item).closest("ul").hasClass("interested")) {
            $(ui.item).detach().appendTo("#categories-source");
            $(ui.item).css("width", "initial");
        } else {
            $(ui.item).detach().appendTo("#categories-chosen");
            $(ui.item).css("width", "210px");
            $(ui.item).css("height", "initial");
        }
    }
```

It puts dragged element in proper `ul` depending if previous one had class `interested`.

**Update**

Also set proper dimensions to the dragged element (because left list is one per line).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wy04t7y/3/)

Comment: yes, thats almost it, I just need to change also display and float. in the left its one item per line, in the right all items are floated. is it possible? see http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/5wy04t7y/2/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery UI, you can take advantage of *droppable* widget. This features two callback, `over` and `out`. Change CSS properties of draggable element whenever it is over or out droppable area.

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n8v4uf16/).

```
$(".columns_all").droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.css("background-color", "lightblue");
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.css("background-color", "");
    }
});
```

## Update

As requested, here is a code for two-way dragging.

```
elwidth = $(".columns_selected li").width(); // used to set element width

// left to right
$(".columns_all").droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.css({
            "background-color": "lightblue",
            width: "auto"
        });
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.css({
            "background-color": "",
            width: elwidth
        });
    },
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.css({
            "background-color": "#ccc"
        });
    }
});

// right to left
$(".columns_selected").droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.css({
            "background-color": "red",
            width: elwidth
        });
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.css({
            "background-color": "",
            width: "auto"
        });
    },
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.helper.css({
            "background-color": "#74ce9c"
        });
    }
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwwb45tw/).

Comment: `out` is not working, its not changing the color back, when its dropped in the right column, also I need it set to the color of the other items in the column (green left, gray right)

Comment: @Legionar you're using old version of jQuery 1.6.4 In my fiddle i'm using 1.9. make sure you using most recent jQuery core and UI. In the fiddle, it's working flawlessly.

Comment: sorry, I am using jQuery 1.10.1, but setted it wrong in jsfiddle, and also I have the newest jQuery UI. I was testing it in your demo, that you sent.

Comment: @Legionar You want only the ones from left to have the color change or the ones from right to left?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69405/discussion-between-ciccolina-and-legionar).